# Need a way to create a cookie so that node js server can access it (cross domain)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a `Node.js` server with `socket.io`. Many domains will communicate with this node server.

I need a way to create a cookie with the domain as my node.js server so that, when a client my node.js server can access this cookie.

This is for identifying the clients on reloads or page navigation with in the domain.

I have searched a lot for this, but couldn't find a solution. I have seen many people leveraging `authorization` event. I am afraid I don't know when this gets triggered and the call backs. I am unsure if this can sent a cookie back to the client.

If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: Have you looked at http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieSession ?

Comment: I just checked the link you shared, but couldn't understand much. From the answers from other related questions, I could understand that I can set a cookie like this  'handshakeData.headers.cookie = "ServerUserID"+"="+"123"+";' path=/;httpOnly: false;"; But not sure how to send it to the client. I couldn't find any documentation related the the 'authorization' event also.